# host only networking and access to some Ip address block

Tags: networking, virtualization

I am using qemu/kvm on ubuntu host.

I want a windows 10 guest (IP Address 192.168.110.102) to have access only to

```
1. Host OS (host has IP 192.168.1.101)
2. The same LAN as the Host (192.168.1.0/24) and nothing else
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @mtak thanks for the link, it does answer my question. However I need more help implementing it for e.g. the option 2. Do I need to configure UFW or IPTable? Sorry I am relatively new to this.

Comment: UFW is a front-end for IPTables, so either would work. In terms of maintainability and upgrade-proof-ness (Engrish :)), I'd choose UFW.

Comment: @mtak thanks once again, can you please share me a link to instructions on how to get this done, I am not sure what keywords to use for searching instructions. "ufw routing"?

Comment: I don't have a link, but a bit of creativity goes a long way. Apply two rules to the traffic coming from the VM. Allow to 192.168.1.0/24 and deny all. In that order (iptables works on a first-match principle)

Comment: @mtak thanks a lot.